# Angular 11 ReactiveForm: How to change form control to a form array(form array inside form array)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a form array with these control

```
this.formBuilder.group({fieldName: [null, Validators.required],
displayName: [null, Validators.required],
fieldType: [0, Validators.required],
defaultValue: [null],
fieldValues: [null],
sortOrder: [null],});
```

I have a task that when I click on a button, it will change the defaultValue control to a form array(currently a form control) with two control.I'm new with Angular and I don't know how to write in Html and Ts file. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Reactive forms provide [`setControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setControl) with which you can replace an existing control. So if you want to make it a formarray with two form controls, it can be achieved the following way:

```ts
this.form.setControl(
  'defaultValue',
  this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.control(''),
    this.formBuilder.control('')
  ])
);
```